# Repeater inside an HTML select tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I am forced to use a select tag so please don't suggest the asp dropdownlist.

My problem is that the select tag is not visible unless there is a **runat=server**. If I put a runat=server, I get an error stating that I **cannot have a repeater inside a HTMLSelect**.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thanks!

```
<select name="medicineName" class="grey-text initialized">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose medicine</option>
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <option value='<%# Eval("id")%>'>
                        <%# Eval("name") %> | <%# Eval("unit") %> | <%#Eval ("quantity") %>
              </option>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

Comment: The asp:dropdownlist control generates a select tag? So why don't you want to use it? You could just bind to it and you'd be sorted.

Comment: Would you mind asking what forces you to use a select and not a dropdownlist?

Comment: <%# Eval("name") %> | <%# Eval("unit") %> | <%#Eval ("quantity") %>

I need to show these three database values in a single option or ListItem. Hence, the name, unit, and quantity.

Could you guide me on your preferred solutions, please? It would be nice

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan, so the only problem with drop down is that you struggle with displaying these values in a single drop down item?

Comment: Yes since I'm new to asp.net. It's my first time to bind multiple values so I'm seeking help. I've only worked with single values in the past :( @Andrei

Comment: @JPaulPunzalan Please see my answer (re: DropDownList issue)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to resolve your problem would be to do:

1. Apply `runat="server"` to the Select.
2. Delete the Repeater

You don't need the `Repeater`, all it will do is loop through a Collection and output in a formatting you build.  From code behind you can actually apply a `DataSource` like the `Repeater`, then it will output in your Select.  How you achieve this:

```
// Build Model:
public class Medicine
{
     public int? Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You have your model, now you would `Query<Medicine>(...)`.  Which would build a `Collection` of your Model.  Then you would do the following:

```
// Dropdown:
drpMedicine.DataSource = Query<Medicine>(...);
drpMedicine.DataBind();
```

Then on your front-end, you would do the following:

```
<select id="drpMedicine" runat="server" datatextfield="Name" datavaluefield="Id"></select>
```

That would allow you to bind your `List` without manually creating your loop.

*Please note that Query is a custom method, which will build and format the data.  You need to do the following.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the usage of a DropDownList control (instead of Repeater), make sure that you concatenate the database columns as one column from your SQL statement.

For example:

```
SELECT id, name + ' | ' + unit + ' | ' + CONVERT(varchar, quantity) AS medicine
FROM medicines_table
```

I assumed that your quantity column is using an integer data type that's why I converted it to a string value.

From your code-behind, you can now set the values for [DataTextField and DataValueField properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// other code here
yourDropDownList.DataTextField = "medicine";
yourDropDownList.DateValueField = "id";
// other code here
```